# Heroku Rails App Not Working After Gemfile change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I removed the braintree gem and added the stripe gem on my web app by removing `gem 'braintree'` and by adding `gem 'stripe'` to my Gemfile.

I forgot to run `bundle install` before I did `git push`.

The push failed by saying

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       The git source `git://github.com/rails/activeresource.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * stripe
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * braintree (~> 2.68.2)
       Bundler Output: The git source `git://github.com/rails/activeresource.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * stripe

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * braintree (~> 2.68.2)
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

When I go to look at what I pushed, it shows that I only changed the Gemfile, not the Gemfile.lock

I wasn't really thinking in the moment, so I ran heroku run bundle install and it still didn't work... Then I realized I needed to run bundle install on my development server, git add, commit and push. I did that and the deployment succeeded.

What I should have done, is then check Heroku to see if the app worked, but instead I kept on going on my dev environment. 3 weeks later, I am now stuck and can't get my production server working and can't help it is because of this. The reason why, is because if I revert back the deployment before the change in gems, the Heroku app works. If I revert to the first successful Heroku deployment after changing the gems, it doesn't work.

To top it all off, it is working in development, but Heroku is only giving me status=500 for anything in the HomeController only. My ProductController and SessionsController work just fine in Heroku. Somebody please help me.

**EDIT: More logs**

```
2017-06-08T00:19:46.287414+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-06-08T00:19:46.287414+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
2017-06-08T00:19:46.287415+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
2017-06-08T00:19:46.287416+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2017-06-08T00:19:48.376028+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:37753
2017-06-08T00:19:48.376189+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-06-08T00:19:48.380496+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 0 (pid: 6) booted, phase: 0
2017-06-08T00:19:48.381809+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 1 (pid: 10) booted, phase: 0
2017-06-08T00:19:48.805034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-06-08T00:19:50.934188+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=apparelpop.herokuapp.com request_id=1c750af7-6e1b-47a8-b53a-173363734cee fwd="71.84.13.91" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=643ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=https
2017-06-08T00:19:51.311080+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=apparelpop.herokuapp.com request_id=1e2ec266-b53f-46c6-96bf-fff047495344 fwd="71.84.13.91" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=4432 protocol=https
2017-06-08T00:30:40.856024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/add_products" host=apparelpop.herokuapp.com request_id=67922ed5-7b11-4c9d-bc4c-9c004ffae29b fwd="71.84.13.91" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=252ms status=200 bytes=3426 protocol=https
2017-06-08T00:30:41.011843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-eabf6168a4491b0270f9a3592275b1703fc9822f8dbe89d4d48747bf988ee588.css" host=apparelpop.herokuapp.com request_id=74c2f89f-192c-4521-9e94-044eee61f28b fwd="71.84.13.91" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=21759 protocol=https
2017-06-08T00:30:41.003143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-bbc24c0db3a1883d36ac5d3c7633860a208f9b559914a4de7f46dd9718df230c.js" host=apparelpop.herokuapp.com request_id=c2139621-68ff-441f-808f-3044d75c0a6d fwd="71.84.13.91" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=44113 protocol=https
2017-06-08T00:30:45.499471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/invoices" host=apparelpop.herokuapp.com request_id=6c72f5ef-6c83-482e-b362-2bd8580b4593 fwd="71.84.13.91" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1085ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=https
```

Comment: Run `heroku logs --tail` command and post log output as an edit or in comments. This will show the real problem and someone can help you solve it.

Comment: All i get is 2017-06-08T00:19:50.934188+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=apparelpop.herokuapp.com request_id=1c750af7-6e1b-47a8-b53a-173363734cee fwd="71.84.13.91" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=643ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=https

Comment: So, your web server isn't running. That output is from the Heroku Router that forwards requests to your server. Did you set up a Procfile describing how to run a Rails app on Heroku?

Comment: Yes. web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers

Comment: check edit for more heroku logs

Comment: So, this is still a heroku router log, not your Rails application log. Are there any log lines with the word `app` in them?

Comment: No, that is everything. When I go to '/add_products' it works just fine. It is just anything in the HomeController like '/' or '/invoices'. You can see my get request to add_products in the log with status=200

Comment: well this led me down the path of finding the app log info... I had to change my production.rb to find the errors... thanks for the tip! i will update with my answer soon enough